# Public CAS server for testing client code

Tags: cas

I am trying to program a CAS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Authentication_Service) client (using phpCAS) for an open-source project, but I need a server to test against.

Are there any public CAS servers out there I can test with (for example, with a default username and pass) just to make sure my code is working?

I have googled every way I can think to ask, and haven't found anything; just instructions for setting up a CAS server, which frankly looks way more complicated than what I want.

Comment: What is CAS in this context? A computational algebra system? Client access service? Authentication?

Comment: Sorry, Authentication.  I will update my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have googled every way I can think to ask, and haven't found anything

If you google for Apereo CAS, you will arrive at this site: https://apereo.github.io/cas which is the official website for CAS. Click on "Demos" in the top navbar, and you'll land on https://apereo.github.io/cas/Demos.html and from the list, if you pick "CAS Web Application Server" you will land on https://casserver.herokuapp.com/cas which acts as a public demo.

Note the big yellow box:

> It is important to note that these are public demo sites, used by the project for basic showcases and integration tests and they can be quite unstable in terms of uptime and availability. They are NOT set up for internal demos as they may go up and down as the project needs without notice.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I knew there had to be something like this, just wasn't catching it.

Comment: Hi @Misagh_Moayyed, do you know a stable `django-cas-server` that would be open source in github? I use this [repository](https://github.com/django-cas-ng/demo-cas-server) whereas it is not stable.

Comment: I went to check the Apereo demos and tried to use the CAS Web Application, but after installing in my nodejs app it indicates "Application Not Authorize to use CAS". Do we need to whitelist our app? if so where? what about if we running local dev?

Comment: I found out that this demo CAS servers act as a test servers for the Apereo project. There will be no way they will whitelist a service, you will have to build your own local CAS server.